# TF-IDF calculation KeyError

Tags: python, tf-idf, keyerror

I want to calculate document frequencies of text documents. First I created the term dictionary and calculated the  term frequencies. I have no problems in these steps, but when I try to use the function below it gives an error:

```
def computeDF(docList):
    df = {}
    df = dict.fromkeys(docList[0].keys(), 0)
    
    for doc in docList:
        for word, val in doc.items():
            if val > 0:
                df[word] += 1

    for word, val in df.items():
        df[word] = float(val)

    return df
```

Called the function like this:

```
dictList = []
for i in range(N):
    # creating dictionary for all documents
    tokens = processed_text[i]
    dictionary = dict.fromkeys(tokens,0)

    # calculation of term frequencies for all documents
    for word in tokens:
        dictionary[word] += 1
        tf = termFreq(dictionary, tokens)
        dictList.append(dictionary)

    df = computeDF(dictList)
```

I called the function with list of 10 dictionaries, because it works with list object.

N = 10 (num of documents)
`dictList` continues like this: [dictList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCpUV.png)

Error:

```
line 155, in <module> df = computeDF(dictList)

line 134, in computeDF df[word] += 1
KeyError: 'flagstaff'
```

It works when I try the function in different python file with same object types. I don't understand what is the problem. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Where you have `df = dict.fromkeys(docList[0].keys(), 0)` you need something like

```
keys = set()
for doc in docList:
    keys = keys.union(set(doc.keys()))
df = dict.fromkeys(docList[0].keys(), 0)
```

That way you have keys for all your docs not just the first one. If you want todo it in one line you can do it like this:

```
keys = set().union(*[set(doc.keys()) for doc in docList])
```

Comment: I got your point, but I'm still getting the same error. I guess there is a problem with my dictionary list, because it gives the error with a term in the dictionary. (KeyError: 'intelligence')

Comment: Are you sure you saved your changes and are you sure it's the same error? It should work now.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, in df = dict.fromkeys(docList[0].keys(), 0) line, I tried both of your answer one by one. The error is still KeyError: 'flagstaff'. @kpie

Comment: I'm sorry I don't believe you. Are you sure you actually saved the changes before running the script?